# virtuemart add to cart button in other component

Tags: php, joomla, include, cart, virtuemart

i write an component for joomla and i use it for the virtuemart Shop component.
The Add To cart button shows, it's also there, but i don't know what i must include, that i press him and the Product is in the cart.

It's another component, i just want to include the button in their. Include works, but there is no function behind.

```
$this->addtocart($product)
```

View.html.php

```
function addtocart ($product) {
        if (!VmConfig::get ('use_as_catalog', 0)) {
            $stockhandle = VmConfig::get ('stockhandle', 'none');
            if (($stockhandle == 'disableit' or $stockhandle == 'disableadd') and ($product->product_in_stock - $product->product_ordered) < 1) {
                $button_lbl = vmText::_ ('COM_VIRTUEMART_CART_NOTIFY');
                $button_cls = 'notify-button';
                $button_name = 'notifycustomer';
                ?>
                <div style="display:inline-block;">
            <a href="<?php echo JRoute::_ ('index.php?option=com_virtuemart&view=productdetails&layout=notify&virtuemart_product_id=' . $product->virtuemart_product_id); ?>" class="notify"><?php echo vmText::_ ('COM_VIRTUEMART_CART_NOTIFY') ?></a>
                </div>
            <?php
            } else {
                $pr_name = $this->getPrDetails($product->virtuemart_product_id, 'product_name');
                $pr_cat = $this->getCat($product->virtuemart_product_id);
                ?>
            <div class="addtocart-area">

                <form method="post" class="product" action="index.php"> 
                    <div class="addtocart-bar">

                        <?php
                        // Add the button
                        $button_lbl = vmText::_ ('COM_VIRTUEMART_CART_ADD_TO');
                        $button_cls = ''; //$button_cls = 'addtocart_button';


                        ?>
                        <?php // Display the add to cart button ?>
                        <span class="addtocart-button">
                            <?php echo shopFunctionsF::getAddToCartButton(true); ?>
            </span>

                        <div class="clear"></div>
                    </div>

                    <input type="hidden" class="pname" value="<?php echo $pr_name ?>"/>
                    <input type="hidden" name="option" value="com_virtuemart"/>
                    <input type="hidden" name="view" value="cart"/>
                    <noscript><input type="hidden" name="task" value="add"/></noscript>
                    <input type="hidden" name="virtuemart_product_id[]" value="<?php echo $product->virtuemart_product_id ?>"/>
                    <input type="hidden" name="virtuemart_category_id[]" value="<?php echo $pr_cat ?>"/>
                </form>
                <div class="clear"></div>
            </div>
            <?php
            }
        }
    }
```

$product is an array of the table. Button shows up, but i need the function behind. What i must include for this? Or does it not work?

Need help, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This code you have shown is an `addToCart` function that just builds markup for the browser. If you're having trouble getting it to actually add a product to the cart, look at what this markup does...

It builds a form which posts several fields to *index.html*. You'll need to inspect the values being sent during that POST (when you click the add to cart button) and the corresponding code on the server to see why a product isn't getting added.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I think best solution is write an own function that include the product in the cart (db entry).. normaly it would be read from the shop after that.

Comment: I guess what I'm saying is if you track down the handling of that POST request from the add to cart button you have, you'll be able to see how they're creating the product (inserting to db) already.

Comment: Yes. Problably i've found a function (add) for the cart.
if (!class_exists('VirtueMartCart'))
                  require(VMPATH_SITE . DS . 'helpers' . DS . 'cart.php');
               $cart = VirtueMartCart::getCart();

Then you do $cart->add(Yourstuff)

That says google. But what need Yourstuff? What array is that?

Comment: Just find one of the existing add to cart buttons that works, then reverse engineer your way into the code that does the insert.

Comment: Thats the problem, i've just searching.. I've build an ajax request with an script which calls the $cart->add() function, in head i give him the product id, but cart ist still empty.. Must i just call the function or more?